# gl_lines and gl_clear in QGLWidget

Tags: opengl, qglwidget

I got a problem with drawing on a QGLWidget. I have several quads on the widget which I can move around when pressing some keys. As long as I just draw quads, everything works fine but now I want to add some lines using:

```
    glBegin(GL_LINE);
glColor3f(c[0], c[1], c[2]);
glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
glEnd;
```

The drawing also works fine, but the clearing of the glwidget doesn't work anymore. Means that I see everything I ever drawed on it. Just to mention.
I tried the same with GLUT using the same initializations and it worked, but since I have switched to Qt it doesn't work anymore.
paintGL(), resizeGL() and initializeGL() are below.

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, -20.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, -10.0f);

glTranslatef(0.0f, -30.0f, -40.0f);
glRotatef(-90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(s_deg, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glRotatef(s_deg2, cos(DEGRAD(s_deg)), sin(DEGRAD(s_deg)), 0.0f);


float colors[8][3] = {
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
    1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, 1.0, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9,
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1,

}; //red, green, blue, red shiny, green shiny, blue shine, light grey, dark grey

for(int i=0;i<glBoxes.size();i++) {
    glBoxes.at(i).setColor(colors[i]);
    glBoxes.at(i).drawCuboid();
    glBoxes.at(i).drawCuboidGrid();
}
```

}

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {    
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
glClearDepth(1.0);
```

}

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {    
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, (float)width, (float)height);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0f, (float)width/(float)height, 0.5f, 100.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

}

any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tokens accepted by glBegin are

- GL_POINTS
- GL_LINES
- GL_TRIANGLES
- GL_TRIANGLE_FAN
- GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP
- GL_QUADS
- GL_QUAD_STRIP

and

- GL_POLYGON

The token used by you, GL_LINE (not the missing trailing *S*) is not valid for glBegin.

---

The statement `glEnd;` will evaluate the address of the function glEnd and silently discard the result. Could it be, that you have a Pascal or Delphi background? In C like languages you have to add a matched pair of parentheses to make it a function call. Functions that don't take a parameter are called with an empty pair of parentheses. E.g. in your case `glEnd();`.

---

Not related to your problem. All of the code in `resizeGL` should go to the head of `paintGL` (use the widget's `width()` and `height()` getters). Also what you have in `initializeGL` belongs to `paintGL`.

The proper use of `initializeGL` is to do one-time initialization, like loading textures, and shaders, preparing FBOs and such.

`resizeGL` is meant to re-/initialize stuff that depends on the window's size and which is quite time consuming to change, like renderbuffers and/or textures used as attachment in FBOs used for window sized post-processing or similar. Setting the projection matrix does not belong there, and neither does the viewport. Those go into `paintGL`.

glDepthFunc, glClearColor and glClearDepth directly influence the drawing process and as such belong with the drawing code.

Also you should not use the immediate mode (glBegin … glEnd) at all. It's been outdated ever since OpenGL-1.1 was released over 15 years ago. Use Vertex Arrays, with the possible addition of Buffer Objects.

Answer (score 1):

`glEnd;` should be `glEnd();`. This may actually fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It must be `GL_LINES` instead of `GL_LINE`. The symbols accepted by `glBegin` are plural (i.e. GL_QUADS, GL_LINE_STRIPS...).

Comment: yes, sorry was a failure in my post, in the programm there is GL_LINES

Answer (score 1):

`GL_LINE` isn't a valid token for `glBegin`.  To draw lines, you need `GL_LINES` (that's subtle, and you're in good company - this is a common mistake).

`GL_LINE` is used to control how polygons are rendered, which is controlled by the `glPolygonMode` function.